# Flexible width button not taking all available space

Tags: macos, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, nib

I'm trying to make modifications to layout of TrackMix app as shown in [Creating Your First Mac App](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/books/RM_YourFirstApp_Mac/Articles/Introduction.html).

[image: TrackMix layout]

I wanted the "Mute" button to take 160px or less. The equivalent CSS rule would be `width: 100%; max-width: 160px; margin: 0 auto;`. I'm not sure how to achieve this in Interface Builder or in code. Here's what I have so far

[image: My layout]

While 71 pixels is indeed less than 160px. Is there a way to make the button take all available space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me:

[image]

I have also added a center constraint + leading and tailing edge constraint to parent container. I've set the leading/tailing constraint priority to 250 because they need to be breakable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. After settings button's content hugging priority to 249 (Xcode gave a nice warning) it works like a charm. I was worried I might never get an answer - it seems OSX developers are either rare or quiet on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You're welcome. If it works, vote up to keep busy OSX devs motivated ;)